# How do I make the image and name of categories show on screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

For this I am using Firebase as the database and Picasso to load the images on screen. After I login I am unable to see the images and the names of each category.

I have used a model name "Category" with setters and getters but these messages keep on coming up on my logcat:

[image: screenshot]

My model looks like this at the moment:

```
public class Category {

    private String name, image;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

This is a sample of my database. it shows the category image link and the name of it.

[image: database structure]

The list of categories are supposed to show in a fragment. This is my fragment class.

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    View myFragment;

    RecyclerView categoryList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder> adapter;

    // Firebase Tings
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference categories;

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance() {
        CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
        return categoryFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        categories = database.getReference("Category");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
        categoryList = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
        categoryList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
        categoryList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadCategories();

        return myFragment;
    }

    private void loadCategories() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder>(
                Category.class,
                R.layout.category_item,
                CategoryViewHolder.class,
                categories
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, final Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.tvCategoryName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.ivCategoryImage);

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.format("%s | %s", adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), model.getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is my CategoryViewHolder class

```
public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView tvCategoryName;
    public ImageView ivCategoryImage;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ivCategoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCategoryImage);
        tvCategoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryName);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }
}
```

I have looked for different solutions view the category image and names, but no luck.

**UPDATE:**
I have updated the [database to this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAL6b.png)

I have tried using these 2 ways of showing the data on device

```
 categories=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");

    /*database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    categories = database.getReference("Category");*/
```

But still no success.

Instead it shows [the same errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZurQ.png). I have not changed my model in any way

Thanks for the help in advance.

P.S thanks for the solutions mentioned before, too bad it did work.

Any more help would be suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The database structure from your link seems to be like this

```
category

|-category

|01

-------name
-------image
```

you should refer to the second category node to be able to reach your data
but you don't seem to do that.

So instead of using these 2 lines of code

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
categories = database.getReference("Category");
```

try to use this

```
DatabaseReference categories;

//and refer to your database like that

categories=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child("Category");
```

according to the link you added this should be the correct way to refer to your database

Answer (score 0):

Your current database structure has `Category` objects nested under the `/Category/Category` node, but the reference you are using for your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is pointing to the parent `/Category` node.

This is causing the errors in your logs - the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is trying to marshal the children of the `/Category` node into the `Category` class, but there are no matching direct children at that location.

To fix this, you can adjust the reference that the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    categories = database.getReference("Category").child("Category");
}
```

Or, change your database structure so that categories are listed as direct children of the `/Category` node:

```
{
  "Category" : {
    "01" : {
      "Name" : "Animals",
      "image" : "..."
    },
    "02" : {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```